# Disable intents registered by other apps

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to disable/unregister intents registered by other apps so that they would not get broadcast messages sent by the system?

Something like this:
[Gemini app](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.seasmind.android.gmappmgr)
 (3rd screenshot)

Is there any similar app with the open source code?

Also, it is possible to remove permissions registered by another app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to disable/unregister intents registered by other apps so that they would not get broadcast messages sent by the system?

Fortunately, that is not possible, except on rooted devices.

> Something like this: Gemini app (3rd screenshot)

As the app notes, this requires root.

> Also, it is possible to remove permissions registered by another app?

As JonTraex notes in [his linked-to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9106832/529691), this is not possible even *with* root.

Comment: Since Gemini app mgr is an android app, I am assuming that it must have done that (disabling intents) using APIs. So if I have a rooted device, how is it possible?

Comment: @KoustubhYadav: "I am assuming that it must have done that (disabling intents) using APIs" -- probably not.

Comment: Installing an .apk file on a rooted device, what else could be the possibility?

Answer (score 2):

I answered a similar question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9106832/529691

If you had bothered to look at their permissions you could see how they are doing it.

---

**SYSTEM TOOLS**

> KILL BACKGROUND PROCESSES Allows an application to kill background
>   processes of other applications, even if memory isn't low.
>
> KILL BACKGROUND PROCESSES Allows an application to kill background
>   processes of other applications, even if memory isn't low.
>
> FORCE STOP OTHER APPLICATIONS Allows an application to forcibly stop
>   other applications.
>
> MEASURE APPLICATION STORAGE SPACE Allows an application to retrieve
>   its code, data, and cache sizes