# Android permissions and permission changing

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

So, a friend and I had a discussion. Is it possible for an app to change the permissions of an other? (If it has the permission or is this straight up not possible) I thought that it is not possible because I couldn’t think of a way to do this implemented in the Android APIs

(The phone is not rooted)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change permissions of another application on Android (rooted)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106343/change-permissions-of-another-application-on-android-rooted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No simply put, this is not possible for good reason. Obviously, there is no real good reason for this other than nefarious purpose.